# How can I implement the ignore(_:for:) method to ignore a button press?

Tags: swift

I wanted to implement a ***UITapGestureRecognizer*** that closes a ***FanMenu*** (a circular based menu around a button with other buttons) when the user press outside of the menu.

---

```
let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap(sender:)))
        tapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        tapRecognizer.delegate = self
        tapRecognizer.require(toFail: doubleTapRecognizer)
        scrollView.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
```

---

```
var planScaleDetermination : PlanScaleDetermination?
    @objc func handleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        if(sender.state == .ended) {
            let point = sender.location(in: viewForTilingView)
            if(fanMenu.isOpen && outerFanMenu.isOpen) {
                fanMenu.close()
                outerFanMenu.close()
                outerFanMenu.isHidden = true
                fanMenu.isHidden = true
            }
            if(isPointInPlanDimensions(point: point)) {
                if(!planControlHelper!.scaleView.isHidden && planScaleDetermination != nil) {
                    if let psd = planScaleDetermination {
                        psd.addPoint(point: MobiPlanPoint(X: point.x, Y: point.y))
                    }
                }
                else if(isModeActive && planControlHelper!.documentationMode == .area && !area!.isCorrectionModeActive) {
                    area!.addPoint(point: MobiPlanPoint(X: point.x, Y: point.y), drawOnly: false)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

If the menu ***isOpen*** it closes it correctly, but it closes it also when I select a button inside the menu. I found the ***ignore(_:for:)*** method that tells the gesture recognizer to ignore a specific press of the given event.

How can I implement the method correctly so that my menu will not close when I select a button?

Implementation of the button looks like this:

```
var outerActionItems : [FanMenuButton] = []
func initOuterFanMenu() {

        outerFanMenu.button = FanMenuButton(
            id: "main",
            image: "baseline_clear_white_18pt_1x",
            color: Color(val: 0xFFFFFFFF)
        )

        outerActionItems = [
            FanMenuButton(
                id: "cancelButton",
                image: "baseline_clear_white_18pt_1x",
                color: Color(val: 0xF55B58)
            ),
            FanMenuButton(
                id: "confirmButton",
                image: "baseline_done_white_18pt_1x",
                color: Color(val: 0xF55B58)
            )
        ]

        outerFanMenu.items = outerActionItems
        outerFanMenu.menuRadius = 110.0
        outerFanMenu.radius = 15.0
        outerFanMenu.duration = 0.35
        outerFanMenu.delay = 0.05
        outerFanMenu.interval = (0, 2.0 * .pi)

        outerFanMenu.onItemDidClick = { button in
            self.contextMenuButtonClicked(buttonId: button.id)
        }

        outerFanMenu.onItemWillClick = { button in
            if(button.id != "rotateMarker") {
                self.outerFanMenu.isHidden = !self.outerFanMenu.isHidden
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you want your tap to not interfere with other interactions, just add this line

tapRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = false

Comment: Tried it. Does not work. If I select a button in my FanMenu it closes it anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if tapped view is menu button:

```
@objc func handleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) { 
   if sender.view is FanMenuButton { return }

   ... your code ... }
```

Comment: I tried it but I never step into it when setting breakpoints there.

Comment: If I understood correctly you whant ignore taps on FanMenuButton's?

Comment: I want to ignore the ***UITapGestureRecognizer***. It should only close the menu when you tap outside of the fanMenu.

Comment: You can check sender.view type. And if it FanMenuButton return from handleTap.

Comment: Cast from 'UIView?' to unrelated type 'FanMenuButton' always fails..

Comment: Also if I check if sender.view is FanMenu it never jumps into it.

Answer (score 0):

Just add another view with the name of the background view and add a gesture recognizer on it. Background view should be behind your view. just an example in objective c, you can translate to swift.

```
  _backgroundView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
  UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(backgroundTapAction:)];
  [_backgroundView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];

- (void)backgroundTapAction:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {
//dismiss your view here.
}
```